# Best way to notationally indicate that a solo phrase in an instrumental section should end

Tags: technique, composition, notation

After writing "solo" over a part intended for one instrumentalist in a section, what's the best way to indicate that the the entire section should again begin playing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of standard conventions for this, depending on the instrumentation you are writing for.

The first, is just writing the word *Tutti* above the music where the rest of the section is to enter.

The second can be used only if there is a specific number of players in the section. For instance, in an orchestral piece with two clarinets, when the solo ends, *a2* is written above where the other player is then suppose to come in. This tells the players that now two people are suppose to play. Similarly, *a3* and sometimes *a4* are used.

Comment: I was staying away from "tutti" due to the fact that I thought that it generally indicates that the entire ensemble should begin playing. Just to be clear, it's safe to use it sectionally as well?

Comment: @Smovies, yes, when "tutti" is written in a part, and especially after the "solo" indication, it means for the entire section to enter.

Comment: It is also possible, for winds and brass, to specify the numbers of all the players on a given staff. So, if 1st and 2nd horns are on the same staff, you could also write (1. 2.) to indicate that a solo ends.